# Oracle XML full text query using CONTAINS, <progression> and INPATH

Tags: oracle, oracle-text, oracle-xml-db-repository

I am struggling to find a way to combine a full-text query progression using `<query>` syntax and an INPATH expression.

Given the next code, Oracle ignores the INPATH expression.

```
SELECT DISTINCT publication.id, SCORE (1)
   FROM TBL_PUBLICATION publication
   WHERE 
         ( ( (CONTAINS (
                     xmlcontent,
                     '(<query>
                         <textquery grammar="CONTEXT" >my text
                           <progression>    
                             <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " "))</rewrite></seq>    
                             <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "{", "}", " NEAR "))</rewrite></seq>    
                             <seq><rewrite>transform((TOKENS, "$(?{", "})", " AND "))</rewrite></seq>
                           </progression>
                         </textquery>
                      </query>) INPATH(//foo/bar)',
                     1) > 0))              
ORDER BY SCORE (1) DESC
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb11sea.htm#1008085 Have you created the index with the section group PATH_SECTION_GROUP?

Comment: @Phil I don't think it is necessary. If instead of `<query>...</query>` I write "my text" the INPATH expression works as expected.